# Is it possible to convert a JSValue into an NSNumber?

Tags: ios, swift, javascriptcore

This will show the following error: 'JSValue' is not convertible to 'NSNumber'. If it's not possible to convert, how should I go about getting the JSValue and assigning it to my NSNumber variable?

```
    var sentences:NSNumber = getSentences.callWithArguments([])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [header file JSValue.h](http://opensource.apple.com/source/JavaScriptCore/JavaScriptCore-7537.65/API/JSValue.h), you need to call `toNumber()` on your `JSValue` object. So it's probably:

```
var sentences:NSNumber = getSentences.callWithArguments([]).toNumber()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
if let sentences = getSentences.callWithArguments([]) as? NSNumber {
    // consume sentences here
}
```

The `if let` structure is probably the simplest access to it since it may not actually BE a number, If that doesn't work, you'll have to go back to `JavaScriptCore` and call `JSValueToNumber`:

```
let sentences = getSentences.callWithArguments([])
let nSentences = JSValueToNumber(context, sentences, nil)
```